# GRUB2 won't use HDMI display

Tags: linux, grub2, hdmi

Hi I wonder if you could help me with my grub menu; I'm not able to see it on my HDMI display, and so I end up just booting the default option unless I can remember how to drive it blindly. My display is an ASUS PB278Q to an [ASUS Z97M-PLUS motherboard](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/Z97M-PLUS/E9678_z97m-plus_guide_V2_web_only.pdf).

I have 3 operating systems installed: Ubuntu Studio 19.10, Xubuntu 19.10, and Linux Mint 19.3.

inxi -Q reports:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz
                      OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Desktop v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8
```

Here is the output of xrandr -q:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Here is my current /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=HDMI-A-2:D"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

The current video choice above comes from the shell script for-loop found at

[Kernel mode setting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting)

which reports this about my system:

```
HDMI-A-1: disconnected
HDMI-A-2: connected
VGA-1: disconnected
```

I believe I did see the menu on my HDMI display some weeks ago, twice. That was long before I began trying to edit  /etc/default/grub.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

NN

Comment: Check if there is an option in your BIOS to set the primary display.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know what you mean and I have looked,  but didn't see anything that looked like what you are talking about.

Comment: I've added a web link to the first graf of your question. Page 3-36 in the linked manual shows the Default Display setting. It's alsoo shown at https://i.imgur.com/92fCfyt.png

Comment: @K7AAY I'm not sure I see what you mean. I found this in the menu, and have tried changing "CPU Graphics Multi-Monitor " to enabled, which has not changed anything. But I'm not sure why it would; in no case is there a PCI card involved here. I'm just trying to point to the HDMI port rather than the VGA port of the onboard built in graphics.

Comment: Are you sure this is  related specifically to GRUB? I just skimmed the [UEFI Specifications](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_1.pdf). There seem to be no functions to chose the output device. To me it looks like output selection is entirely up to the EFI firmware. GRUB would use whatever was set-up for it. Only the kernel will load the drivers necessary to manage outputs later in the boot process.